# Anyway to use data properties in text passed to slot?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue setup like so:

```js
Vue.component('custom-component', {
  template: '<div><slot></slot></div>',
  data: function() {
    return {
      parent_data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('sub-component', {
  props: {
    dataProp: {
      default: []
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      data: []
    }
  },
  template: '<div class="subs">{{data.length}}<slot></slot></div>',
  mounted: function() {
    this.data = this.dataProp;
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#root'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="root">
  <custom-component>
    hello
    <sub-component>
      sub component hello
    </sub-component>
  </custom-component>
</div>
```

The `parent_data` property is actually defined via Vue Resource in an ajax call, though it does not appear that this has anything to do with that.

You'll see that we get "hello 0 sub component hello" output in the browser. Okay, cool. So I figured I would fiddle around with it and try and put some of the text into the component's text slot, like so:

```js
Vue.component('custom-component', {
  template: '<div><slot></slot></div>',
  data: function() {
    return {
      parent_data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('sub-component', {
  props: {
    dataProp: {
      default: []
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      data: []
    }
  },
  template: '<div class="subs"><slot></slot></div>',
  mounted: function() {
    this.data = this.dataProp;
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#root'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="root">
  <custom-component>
    hello
    <sub-component>
      {{data.length}}sub component hello
    </sub-component>
  </custom-component>
</div>
```

But this no longer works how I expected it to. What do I have to do in order to get this example to work?

The more-close-to-reality portion of this question looks something like this:

```js
Vue.component('custom-component', {
  template: '<div><slot></slot></div>',
  data: function() {
    return {
      parent_data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    //this.$http.get('/page/here').then(results=> this.parent_data = results, console.error );
  }
});

Vue.component('sub-component', {
  props: {
    dataProp: {
      default: []
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      data: []
    }
  },
  template: '<div class="subs"><slot></slot></div>',
  mounted: function() {
    this.data = this.dataProp;
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#root'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="root">
  <custom-component>
    hello
    <sub-component :data-prop="parent_data">
      {{data.length}} sub component hello
    </sub-component>
  </custom-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reference data from the child inside the slot, you need to use [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots).

Here is your last example updated to use scoped slots.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component('custom-component', {
  template: '<div><slot :parent_data="parent_data"></slot></div>',
  data: function() {
    return {
      parent_data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    //this.$http.get('/page/here').then(results=> this.parent_data = results, console.error );
  }
});

Vue.component('sub-component', {
  props: {
    dataProp: {
      default: []
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      subData: this.dataProp
    }
  },
  template: '<div class="subs"><slot :sub-data="subData"></slot></div>',
  mounted: function() {
    console.log(this.dataProp)
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#root'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <custom-component>
    <template scope="{parent_data}">
      hello
      <sub-component :data-prop="parent_data">
        <template scope="props">
          {{props.subData.length}} sub component hello
        </template>
      </sub-component>
    </template>
  </custom-component>
</div>
```

Essentially, you expose the data you want to be able to use in the child's slot as a property on the slot,

```
<slot :parent_data="parent_data"></slot>
```

and then you have to wrap the content you want to use in the slot with a `template` that has the keyword `scope`.

```
<template scope="props">
  {{props.subData.length}} sub component hello
</template>
```

The expression in the `scope` property of template defines how you will access the data from the child. In the example just above, I used `scope="props"` which will mean that all the properties passed on the slot will be available as properties of `props`. You can also use object destructuring inside your scope expression to just get the properties you want to use, as in `scope="{parent_data}"`.